# Why does python stop on subprocess exit?

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess

I'm using Python's `subprocess.call()` to run a a series of python scripts that each run Matlab scripts. Trouble is, once the first Matlab script ends.

The outer Python script parses a directory of csv files for settings to run experiments based on each line of the csv files. For each experiment, it calls a python program to run parse the data and feed into Matlab. Matlab, then runs each experiment. Except that the entire thing exits after the first time matlab is run. Could Matlab exiting its sub-subprocess bring down the entire thing?

```
 for line in csvfile:
      if debug:
          print 'Experiment %d' % count

      ts = line.split(',')
      startStamp=ts[0]
      cmdargs = ['python prep_lssvm.py']
      cmdargs.append(str(site))
      cmdargs.append(str(startStamp))
      cmdargs.append(str(daysTraining))

      if debug:
          print cmdargs

      for i in range(len(argv)-2):
          cmdargs.append(str(argv[i+2]))

      command = ' '.join(cmdargs)

      if debug:
          print command

      call(command,shell=True)
      #Never goes past here<<<<<<=======================
      dirname = ''.join([site,'_',str(count)])
      mkdir(dirname)
      call(''.join(['mv ',site,'/*.txt ',dirname]),shell=True,stdout=outfile)
```

Comment: any specific reason to use `shell=True` in line `call(command,shell=True)`

Comment: This may be rehashing the obvious, but did you put `print` statements in just after (and just before) calling the command, to make _sure_ that it's really that line where the process exits?

Comment: @avasal Matlab was crashing with shell=False

Comment: @RolandSmith - No exceptions thrown

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky - Yes, I took stuff out to make this bit more readable

Comment: @user1727109 OK, well, I would have left those particular print statements in, because they show how you have narrowed down exactly where the problem is, but it's probably not such a big deal. It's possible that you are actually crashing the Python interpreter, but in that case this is probably going to be a tough question to answer unless someone can reproduce the issue. Certainly any other diagnostic information you can come up with would be a useful addition to the question.

Comment: @user1727109: Capture and print out the return values from the `subprocess.call` functions. If they are non-zero, you have a problem. How are you calling matlab in the `prep_lssvm.py` script?

Comment: It is probably worthwhile to try using subprocess.check_call and/or subprocess.check_output (iff Python 2.7+) instead of subprocess.call-- that way you can check whether a CalledProcessError is raised. Also, if you just throw ``command`` into a shell, what happens? Does the matlab process run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have solved this through rubber-duck debugging.

I was calling the MATLAB script through Popen(), which executes asynchronously, rather than call(), which executes synchronously. Changing all instances of Popen to call appears to have solved the problem.